# wrap_content does not work in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]
The two `button` in the following code, were set to `wrap_content` and no padding. However, there is still some padding in the vertical orientation. If I set the `android:layout_height` to a fixed parameter, the padding could disappear. But I do want to use `wrap_content` instead of a fixed height.

*EDIT:*
Now, I have to use DIP, which is not recommended, as text size to ensure the text in the button while using a fixed height in DIP.  Looking forward to a better solution!

```
<LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/account_balance"/>

                    <LinearLayout 
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView 
                            android:id="@+id/tvBa"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                        <ImageButton 
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="#00000000"
                            android:src="@drawable/video_list_price"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/record_selector"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:text="@string/charge_record"/>

                <Button 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/charge_selector"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:text="@string/charge"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: then rightnow you have use height wrapcontent...,then what you want??

Comment: where are you getting some padding.. can u post snap shot

Comment: Yes, I am using wrap_content. But I got some unexpected padding in the button

Comment: after giving wrap_content have you remove this  **android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"** from button?

Comment: should I remove the `android:layout_marginLeft` ?

Comment: @visheshchandra Thank you for answer. I add the `android:gravity="center_vertical` to this root `LinearLayout`, and it does not work.

Comment: @ZhangLei I think this background image problem, can you remove background drawable attribute or set any color code for testing and then check..

Comment: @visheshchandra I tried to use `#ff00ff00` as the background. But, it still does not work.

Comment: @ZhangLei Problem with button so you can use TextView instead of Button

Answer (score 0):

By default container content align top.

```
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/account_balance"/>

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/tvBa"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <ImageButton 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#00000000"
                        android:src="@drawable/video_list_price"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

This content is taking more height compare to Button.

```
            <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/record_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:text="@string/charge_record"/>
```

So actually buttons are not having padding now, but it is taking more space due to first item of your root LinearLayout.

Add one more attribute in your root LinearLayout. **android:gravity="center_vertical"**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#756846">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
android:layout_weight="1.0"
```

And change the 0dp value to wrap_content

--EDITED

You have 2 potential sources of the padding:
first one is initial button backgroud sizes - it will not be scaled down, only up

Second one is the default style for button - just set padding = 0dp

Comment: This is parameter of the vertical linear layout, seems it has nothing to do with the two buttons. I tried, and it does not work for me. Thank you for reply

Comment: Yes it has "something" to those buttons, if the weight is set to something and the buttons has no weight set the element with weight tries to get as much space as it can.

Comment: Yes, As the root layout is horizontal, I set the weight to keep the buttons in the right side of root layout. But the height of buttons in vertical orientation is not affected by this weight.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was exited when I saw "just set padding = 0dp", it might work for me! Then, I tried and unfortunately found the view same as before...

Comment: How do you creating the background for buttons?

Comment: I use a selector xml with series of different 9.png for different status.

Comment: As vishesh suggested, I used "#ff00ff00" as background instead, the size is same as the 9.png. So, the background is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add minHeight and minWidth to your button as 0dp

```
 <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/record_selector"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:text="@string/charge_record"/>
```